# Interview Golang test improvements

Tags: go

I've been interviewing for some Golang jobs and this was a test that I was assigned.

**FYI: I'm posting this question to improve my skills and see what I could've done differently to make it better.**

**I think it would also benefit other people interviewing for golang jobs knowing what could be done if anything similar is asked to them**

I've worked on it and received a no-go from the company with these comments:

```
 - very basic solution
 - read whole input stream into memory
 - sleeps for the interval every 50 messages
 - very simple tests
 - does not check HTTP status codes,
 - sends non-errors (nils) to error channel
 - checks for context error values instead of done channel
 - new HTTP client for every request send
 - no read readme with design explanation
 - message bursts may exhaust the target server
 - passes pointers to functions
```

How would you have done it, how would you change the code to be OK with the requirements?

This is the test:

***The Library***

> Write a library that implements an HTTP notification client. A client is
> configured with a URL to which notifications are sent. It implements a
> function that takes messages and notifies about them by sending HTTP
> POST requests to the configured URL with the message content in the request
> body. This operation should be non-blocking for the caller.

> A great number of messages might arrive at once, so make sure to handle
> spikes in notification activity and don’t overload the event-handling service
> or exhaust your file descriptors. But be efficient and don’t just send requests
> serially.

> Allow the caller to handle notification failures in case any requests should
> fail.

***The Executable***

> Write a small program that uses the library above. It should read stdin and
> send new messages every interval (should be configurable). Each line should
> be interpreted as a new message that needs to be notified about.
> The program should implement graceful shutdown on SIGINT.

> Example usage information for clarification purposes (the solution doesn’t
> have to reproduce this output):
> usage: notify --url=URL []

> Flags:
> --help Show context-sensitive help (also
> try --help-long and --help-man).
> -i, --interval=5s Notification interval
> Example call:
> $ notify --url http://localhost:8080/notify < messages.txt

This is the repository with the code:

https://github.com/domenicomastrangelo/notifier

Comment: The description of the goal is problematic. See it asks `This operation should be non-blocking for the caller.`, yet, a bit later it also wants to `Allow the caller to handle notification failures in case any requests should fail.`. If the caller needs to handle errors, then it must wait for completion of the task.

Comment: That I was able to accomplish, cause I return the errors via a channel and the caller is able to handle them asynchronously without having to wait for the whole function to finish

Comment: poking on your code to evaluate my understanding i came up with that https://go.dev/play/p/Sr0KCauaFPU It did not help me produce a review of your code, i feel overwhelmed by the level of explanations to provide. not sure where to start either.

Comment: `- does not check HTTP status codes,` this is a non argument. There is no contract definition to write error handling implementation for.

Comment: `- checks for context error values instead of done channel` this is perfectly fine, there is no issue with the call to ctx.Err

Comment: `- passes pointers to functions` this is not a valid argument.

Comment: i figured i left an useless parameter in the notify method, it was a mistake, among possibly some others, anyways. https://go.dev/play/p/bnLKsLg1Thj

Comment: with the latest runtime a neat variation is like https://go.dev/play/p/bTeNGCz55cX?v=gotip